# Download file from AWS EC2 instance to local host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-permissions, scp

I'm trying to download access logs from an AWS EC2 instance to my local machine using the following command:

```
scp -i private-key.pem ec2-user@ec2-public-dns-address:/path/to/filename
```

But I keep getting an error saying `"Permission Denied"` (rather than `"Permission Denied (publickey)"`).  Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, you are trying to download a file, to which your default user doesn't have access. Example: downloading a db dump from `/tmp/dump/` to which only `root` user has access.

If that is the case, ssh on the instance, move/copy the file to a location accessible for your user, and make it the owner of the file, and then ssh out and `scp`.

Comment: what is "your user" and how do you make it the owner of the file?

Comment: update 10 seconds later:  still not sure what you mean, but mine is working now anyway.

Comment: @zkurtz I meant the linux user to which the OP logs in. To make a user the owner of a file, you will need to do `sudo chown user:group filename`.